# Date variable works, but functions on it do not

Tags: typescript, typescript1.4

I'm using TypeScript 1.4 in an ASP.NET MVC 5 project.

I have a field of type Date, and it works partially:

```
var dob: Date = result.dateOfBirth;
alert(dob);
var dobAsString = dob.toDateString();
```

In the code above, the first two lines work, showing the value as "1968-11-16T00:00:00", as expected. But the last line doesn't work, in fact the rest of the code below that line isn't even executed -- it just breaks, without error message.

This behavior persists no matter which Date function I apply in the last line; I could also use `dob.getFullYear()` etc. and it would fail every time. Yet the variable is of the right type and has the right value. The compiler also finds the Date functions, it compiles without a hitch but at runtime it fails. Any ideas?

Comment: Sorry, I corrected it now.

Comment: That's a strange alert - when I alert a date object, i see the date in a completely different format, although that may be browser specific. Are you sure `result.dateOfBirth` is really a `Date` object and not a string representing a date? Is it possible there's a `try/catch` around this code that is swallowing the error silently?

Comment: There's no `try/catch`, and `dob` is strongly-typed as a `Date`.

Comment: Typescript only enforces types at compile time, not at runtime. If, at runtime, your `result` through some fluke happens to have the number `42` or the string `"carrot"` as the value of `dateOfBirth`, Typescript cannot detect this and work around it. Can you `alert(typeof dob)` or `alert(Object.prototype.toString.call(dob))` to verify that it is indeed what you think it should be?

Comment: You are right! It was a string! I thought that this was not possible; since `result.dateOfBirth` is strongly typed as a `Date`, how can it turn into a string? I don't get that. But anyway, you are absolutely right. Thank you!

Comment: I changed the top line to `var dob: Date = new Date(result.dateOfBirth.toString());` and that does the job. Thank you again!

Comment: Typescript's type specifications are just *compiler hints* - the compiler verifies that such operations are possible on such types, but it does not create any constructors/conversion code to enforce those types at runtime. If you use Typescript to specify "this AJAX call returns an object whose `dateOfBirth` property is a `Date`", the compiler will believe you, and there won't be any runtime code to verify this.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

There are two aspects to this one. The first is that you need to parse the date, as you have a string representation currently. The second is that your `result` variable doesn't have type information.

```
var result = {
    dateOfBirth: '1968-11-16T00:00:00'
};

// Error, cannot convert string to date
var a: Date = result.dateOfBirth;

// Okay
var b: Date = new Date(result.dateOfBirth);

var result2: any = result;

// Okay (not type information for result2)
var c: Date = result2.dateOfBirth;
```

When you get back a JSON message, you can apply an interface to it that describes what the server has send, in order to catch problems in your TypeScript code - such as the one you found. This will stop the problem occurring again in the future (although doesn't check the supplied JSON matches the interface)... the example below assumes `result` currently has the `any` type.

```
interface NameYourResult {
    dateOfBirth: string;
}

var r: NameYourResult = result;
```

Comment: You would be using the interface to describe the JSON message, so yes - you could have an error in the interface definition, but *only* there (and not littered throughout your code base). You would be using the interface to allow TypeScript to ensure the code *using* the message didn't make a mistake - not to validate the response from the server. i.e. you get 50% of the type safety using the interface, 0% if you don't use the interface.