# Typescript not recognizing Date as Date?

Tags: typescript

I don't know what's going on here... but apparently TS is not recognizing Date as Date, instead it thinks it is a string.

Here's the code I use to save the `Date`:

```
var validUntil = new Date();

validUntil.setSeconds(validUntil.getSeconds() + tokenResponse.expires_in);
tokenResponse.valid_until = validUntil;
```

And this is my `TokenResponse` class:

```
export class TokenResponse {
    access_token: string;
    token_type: string;
    expires_in: number;
    valid_until: Date;
    error: string;
    error_description: string;
}
```

And here is where the exception is thrown:

```
userToken && userToken.valid_until.getTime()  >= new Date().getTime()
```

Here's the exception:

[image]

Any ideas on what's wrong?

Thanks!

**EDIT**

By the way, I don't think it's related to [Date variable works, but functions on it do not](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30118383/date-variable-works-but-functions-on-it-do-not) since I'm creating a new `Date`

Comment: Post a complete minimal example reproducing the problem. We have no idea what userToken is, among other things.

Comment: @JBNizet it comes from my API. `userToken == TokenResponse`

Comment: If it comes from your API, I guess it's JSON, and JSON doesn't have Dates. Only string, number, boolean. And a JSON object will never be an instance of any class. Again, a complete example would help.

Comment: @JBNizet I thought the information there would be enough. Is there anything specific that would help? I receive the response from the server (1st piece of code), my class is `TokenResponse` and when I try to use it it's not loading as Date (apparently)

Comment: @JBNizet you are correct about JS, though I'm creating a new instance of Date. I'm not relying on the response.

Comment: Well, then you have your answer. An object created by parsing JSON is a plain old object, not an instance of any class. And it doesn't contain Date, because JSON doesn't have support for a Date type. This is still jus conjecture, since you won't post the code that shows how userToken is created.

Comment: @JBNizet Well, I appreciate your time trying to help. As I said I thought the **important** part was there, it seems like it wasn't. According to David below the problem seems to be related to saving the information locally - information I forgot to provide. Anyway, to answer your question, tokenResponse/userToken is a ASP.NET WebApi response to a login request. All I do is create the `Date` type and save it locally.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In code that isn't posted here, the value of `userToken.validUntil` is being set as a string. You will see that if you check `typeof userToken.validUntil` before the part of the code where calling `getTime()` errors.

Make sure when setting `userToken.validUntil` that you always assign a `Date` object to it. If you're deserializing JSON to `userToken`, then make sure the deserializer converts date strings to date objects or for a quick fix do (though not recommended):

```
userToken.validUntil = new Date(userToken.validUntil as any);
```

Note the following:

```
var o = { d: new Date() };
localStorage.setItem("test", JSON.stringify(o));
o = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("test"));
typeof o.d === "string"; // true
```

Comment: Thanks David, the only time I set `validUntil` is there :/ The only thing I can think of is maybe the local storage is changing the type?

Comment: I just checked your update. Isn't that the same as what I was doing? `var validUntil = new Date();

validUntil.setSeconds(validUntil.getSeconds() + tokenResponse.expires_in);
tokenResponse.valid_until = validUntil;`

Comment: Ok... so the problem is related to the storage... is there a way to force it to save `Date`?